# How can I handle the Return key in a CEdit control?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, cedit

How can I handle the <kbd>Return</kbd> key (`VK_RETURN`) in a `CEdit` control? The `CEdit` control is parented to a `CDialog`.

Answer (score 16):

You could also filter for the key in your dialog's PreTranslateMessage. If you get `WM_KEYDOWN` for `VK_RETURN`, call `GetFocus`. If focus is on your edit control, call your handling for return pressed in the edit control.

Note the order of clauses in the if relies on short-circuiting to be efficient.

```
BOOL CMyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN &&
        pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN &&
        GetFocus() == m_EditControl)
    {
        // handle return pressed in edit control
        return TRUE; // this doesn't need processing anymore
    }
    return FALSE; // all other cases still need default processing
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer is to handle the [WM_GETDLGCODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645425.aspx) / [OnGetDlgCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t83978eh.aspx) message. In there you can specify that you want all keys to be handled by your class.

```
UINT CMyEdit::OnGetDlgCode()
{
    return CEdit::OnGetDlgCode() | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make certain the Edit Control style ES_WANTRETURN is set in the dialog resource for the control

Comment: This does not work. This is not what I want. I want to get RETURN key AND do something. Not just allow entering RETURN key.

Comment: Then you'll need to subclass the edit control and handle the WM_CHAR or KeyDown messages which are answered in other SO questions.  OR within the dialog's MessageMap, handle Edit Change messages from the control (sent for every character).

Comment: ES_WANTRETURN is *only* applicable for multi-line text boxes.

Comment: While not what the op was looking for (perhaps edit answer to reflect that), this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the <kbd>Return</kbd> key closes an MFC dialog. This is, because the <kbd>Return</kbd> key causes the `CDialog`'s `OnOK()` function to be called. You can override that function in order to intercept the <kbd>Return</kbd> key. I got the basic idea from [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/102589/how-to-use-the-enter-key-from-edit-controls-in-a-dialog-box) (see *Method 3* at the end).

First, make sure that you have added a member for the edit control to your dialog using the [Class Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748520.aspx), for example:

```
CEdit m_editFind;
```

Next, you can add the following function prototype to the header file of your dialog:

```
protected:
    virtual void OnOK();
```

Then you can add the following implementation to the *cpp* file of your dialog:

```
void CMyDialog::OnOK()
{
    if(GetFocus() == &m_editFind)
    {
        // TODO: Add your handling of the Return key here.
        TRACE0("Return key in edit control pressed\n");

        // Call `return` to leave the dialog open.
        return;
    }

    // Default behavior: Close the dialog.
    CDialog::OnOK();
}
```

Please note: If you have an *OK* button in your dialog which has the ID `IDOK`, then it will also call `OnOK()`.
If this causes any problems for you, then you have to redirect the button to another handler function.
How to do this is also described in *Method 3* of [the article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/102589/how-to-use-the-enter-key-from-edit-controls-in-a-dialog-box) that I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this problem myself.  After a little experiment, a simple way existed if you just want to get the do something (after some editing etc) on the return (not specific for which editor you have focus) - I would just create a invisible default button, and let that button handle the 'return' key instead of default Ok button (of course, Ok button should be set default key to false)